# How should I uninstall node if Iave installed it using node-and-npm-in-30-seconds.sh?

Tags: node.js

I have installed node using https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

How can I completely uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally, beside install will have uninstall commands. Try this

```
make uninstall
```